# Kvantum overrides application color scheme

Tags: colors, kde5

Kvantum theme in KDE overrides application color scheme and hasn't any option in .kvconfig file regarding tooltip background color.Does anybody know how can I change the tooltip background color in Kvantum?
I'm using KDE 5.12 on ubuntu 18.04.
Thanks

Comment: How did you install Kvantum? The reason I'm asking is that the Kvantum devs seemed, at least in my opinion,  to always suggest using the latest version and that version isn't available in Ubuntu 18.04's default repositories. So I didn't look at Kvantum further.

Comment: v0.14.2 - Currently latest version

Comment: But from where did you install it? And what is the package name?

Comment: https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum/tree/master/Kvantum

Comment: Also mojave CT theme from https://store.kde.org/p/1288051/

Comment: You should ask tsujan himself. I have asked him questions like that in the past ([here](https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum/issues/277#issuecomment-431369215) and [here](https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum/issues/279#issuecomment-432674311)) and got very quick and useful response.