# Should I install Ubuntu on primary or logical partition

Tags: boot-partition

Should I install Ubuntu on primary or logical partition. Is there any speed comparison?

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Comment: to add to pilot6: the only thing that matters is when you have an ssd and a hdd. the ssd will be quicker for booting and initial start (so / and /home/*/.config/ but that is taking your  question a bit further than "partitions".

Comment: If you are using gpt (Which you should be) all partitions are the same, in effect primary. Partition tools may still say primary or logical. The only reason for MBR(msdos) anymore is if you have to install Windows in BIOS boot mode. Even old BIOS only systems can use gpt if only Ubuntu. I use gpt on my 2006 laptop, mostly retired as battery died, but now has Kubuntu 20.04 just to see if it works.

Comment: This has already been covered in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/121197/1195532).

Answer (score 0):

If by speed you mean access time, it only depends on the type of the hard drive (SSD or HDD) and the controller model ( manufacture, technology, etc. ), so being logical or primary is irrelevant.