# Is it safe to delete an middle partition of the disc for installing Ubuntu (dual boot with Windows 10)?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, system-installation

My laptop uses MBR partitioning scheme. Currently there are already 4 partition on my disk, and 3 of them are primary partitions. A system reserved primary partition, the Windows C: partition (primary), another primary partition D: and an extended partition comprising 2 logical drives E: and F:

Partitions on my disk:

[image: Partition on my disk (image)]

I am planning to install Ubuntu 20.04 on one of the partitions. I am willing to allocate about 200GB to Ubuntu. Do I need a primary partition to install Ubuntu? In that case, I would have to delete the D: partition, but I am worried if it is safe to delete an intermediate partition? (as there are E: and F: partitions).

I want to install the Ubuntu bootloader (GRUB2) on the Ubuntu partition itself so that I don't mess up my Windows bootloader. I have read that for MBR partition scheme, the system can only boot from primary partitions. Can I use a logical partition to install Ubuntu on it, or should I only go for a primary partition?

I am asking for the best and safest way to dual boot with Ubuntu. Considering my partition scheme, can you suggest the best possible way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu installation partitioning: Logical or primary?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121197/ubuntu-installation-partitioning-logical-or-primary) and [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/q/343268/)

Comment: Do your Windows partitioning using Windows Disk Management. If it won't let you delete the partition use an extended partition.

Comment: Windows will not boot Ubuntu without third party hacks. With old BIOS/MBR configuration you only have one MBR and BIOS boots from that MBR. Grub will boot working Windows, so typically better to install grub to MBR, not to partition. Windows only boot from primary NTFS partition with boot flag. Grub does not use boot flag. With BIOS/MBR, be sure to have both current versions of  Windows repair/recovery flash drive & Ubuntu live installer to make repairs.

Comment: @oldfred I was thinking of using EasyBCD (third-party software) to choose between Windows and Ubuntu when booting, if I install Ubuntu bootloader to the Ubuntu partition. What would you recommend: EasyBCD or GRUB2 ?

Comment: @C.S.Cameron My actual worry is: Suppose I use the D: partition for Ubuntu. Then, would Windows will recognise the E: and F: drives. Actually, I have seen people shrinking space from the last drive that is present in the disk, I was wondering if only the last drive should be used for dual-booting.

Comment: Not that I've heard of. I think Windows sees all partitions on the drive it just doesn't know what is in the Linux partitions. I used EasyBCD for dual booting Win XP and Win 7 I would use GRUB2 if Linux is involved.

Comment: Windows with BIOS/MBR also has a bug. It does not correctly see Linux partitions. Major updates like updating 7 to 10 will remove partition table entry. Data is still there and entry just has to be restored. So good backups are required and know your partitions in detail.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need a primary partition to install Ubuntu?

Short answer, "No, You don't need a primary partition to install Ubuntu". For more clarification see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121197/ubuntu-installation-partitioning-logical-or-primary).

First and foremost, backup everything that you think is important, messing with partitions are risky. Secondly, while installing you should choose [something else](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) option and create manual partitions for ubuntu installation alongside windows.
In case after installation you cannot boot into ubuntu, check the boot order and change it to Ubuntu Grub bootloader.